# nested query filter _ Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I keep it simple. I have 3 models.

```
 class C(models.model):
    some_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)

 class B(models.model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(C)

 class A(models.model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

I need a query filter that gets A.a.b.some_field = True. how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter your `A` objects that satisfy this condition with:

```
A.objects.filter(a__b__some_field=True)
```

This will generate a query that looks, more or less like:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.a_id = b.id
JOIN c ON b.b_id = c.id
WHERE c.some_field = 1
```

The double underscore (`__`) can be used to look "through" relations (like `ForeignKey`s, `OneToOneField`s and `ManyToManyField`s). In case it is ...-to-many field, this is *existentially* quantified. But here the `ForeignKey`s are many-to-one relations, so that does not matter.

> **Note**: `ForeignKey`s to `B` (or `C`) is typically named `b` (or `c`), not `a` (or `b`), since that is the name of the current model. The name of a relation typically specifies how the object(s) it targets relate to the current model.