# Django 3.0 Python 3.* - Nested Queries and Filters

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset, django-3.0

Scenario: Form that give values to filter some records. I have 4 models **A**, **B**, **C** and **D**.

**A** Have `OneToOne` relationship with **B**

**B** Have `ManyToOne` relationship with **C**

**C** Have `ManyToOne` relationship with **D**

Form value given is a field in model **D**, and the record that I'll retrieve is in model **A**

I've Tried:

```
records= A.objects.filter(
            a_field = "form_given_value_1",
            B__b_field = C.objects.filter( 
                c_field = D.objects.filter(
                    d_field=form_given_value_2
                )
            )
        )
```

I got that error:

> SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated

then after some search I tried given answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377931/nested-query-filter-django):

```
records = A.objects.filter(
             a_field = "form_given_value_1",
             B__b_field__c_field__d_field = form_given_value_2
          )
```

It doesn't give me errors but it doesn't give records also!..

how to achieve that approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** you need to check if `form_given_value_*` is null because if any is equal to null (no input) the `filter()` will return nothing

**Second** after check you need to pass filters to `filter()` upon your check

We achieve that like below:

```
    from django.db.models import Q

    filters = Q()
    if form_given_value_1:
        filters &= Q(a_field = "form_given_value_1",)
    if form_given_value_2:
        filters &= Q(B__b_field__c_field__d_field = form_given_value_2,)

    records = A.objects.filter(filters)
```